# Problems with "for" inserting into a database

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, selenium, selenium-webdriver

After scraping with Selenium (a list of 20 names for Test1 and a list of 20 names for Test2), I would like to save these in the database: in a single vertical column called "name". So I would like to save 40 different rows, all in the same name column, so 40 different names. Scraping happens correctly. He scrapes all 40 names

There is some problem in inserting into the database: only a few names are saved (for example only 5, 6, 7 names), but all are scraped regularly. How to solve? Should i use **append**? if so how? what should i change to my code? Obviously also print the result in the console as I did

Can you show me where I am wrong in entering the database? Thank you

```
    #Test 1
    driver.minimize_window()
    driver.get("link")
    for Test1 in driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[href^='/xxxx'][class^='xxxx']"):
        Test1_text = Test1.text
        print(Test1_text)
    driver.close


    #Test 2
    driver.minimize_window()
    driver.get("link")
    for Test2 in driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[href^='/xxxx'][class^='xxxx']"):
        Test2_text = Test2.text
        print(Test2_text)
    driver.close


# INSERT IN DATABASE
    con = sqlite3.connect('/home/blablabla/Desktop/Database.db')
    cursor = con.cursor()

    Values = ((Test1_text,), (Test2_text,))
    sqlite_insert_query = 'INSERT INTO NewTest (Name) VALUES (?);'
    count = cursor.executemany(sqlite_insert_query, Values)
    con.commit()
    print(" ")
    print("Record inserted successfully ", cursor.rowcount)
    records_added_Risultati = records_added_Risultati + 1
    cursor.close()
```

Comment: when you say Test1_text = Test1.text, you lose the preceding value.

Comment: @Jeremy Kahan Yes. I do this because otherwise I have problems in the database, because the name of the saved data does not come out in the database, but a long text with written selenium34803948 (something like that, I don't remember well). Could you help me to have the whole list of for correctly saved in the database? Only a few names are saved.

Comment: Oh, I understand why you need the ,text, I just mean the Test1.text for your first entry, say, is no longer there when you get around to writing to the database. There would be 2 ways to go here. 1. Store the values in an array and add later (your "append idea") or 2. Write them to the database as you go along.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue would appear to be that Test1_text and Test2_text get updated each time through the loop, so when the loop ends they are holding only the last value found. So your SQL Insert is going to insert just those two last values (I cannot explain how you would get 5, 6, or 7 unless maybe it's interpreting James D. Com as 3 different names). There would be 2 ways to address this. I am sketching here, not writing flawless code because I cannot easily test it.

Way 1: Write name to database immediately. So you would bring this part up before your first test:

```
con = sqlite3.connect('/home/blablabla/Desktop/Database.db')
cursor = con.cursor()
sqlite_insert_query = 'INSERT INTO NewTest (Name) VALUES (?);'
records_added = 0
```

and where you have your `print(Test1_text)` add in:

```
count = cursor.execute(sqlite_insert_query, (Test1_text,))
records_added = records_added + 1# or say + count, should be the same
```

(no need to executemany).

Thus:

```
Test1_text = Test1.text
print(Test1_text)#put first so in case of error, you know where it happened
count = cursor.execute(sqlite_insert_query, (Test1_text,))
records_added = records_added + 1
```

and similarly where you have your `print(Test2_text)`

```
Test2_text = Test2.text
print(Test2_text)#put first so in case of error, you know where it happened
count = cursor.execute(sqlite_insert_query, (Test2_text,))
records_added = records_added + 1
```

I think your commit and close (the close for sure stays put) can stay put, but you can experiment with commit after each insertion. Also, no `Values=` or `execute`s happen below outside the loops. And after your con.commit, you could now say:

```
print("Records inserted successfully: ", records_added)
```

Way 2. Accumulate the values

```
tests1_and2_text=[]
```

somewhere before the first for loop. After you print test1_text do a `tests1_and2_text.append((Test1_text,))` and do similarly where you print `Test2_text`.
Later, set your `Values = tests1_and2_text` and see if that works (it should; you may need to tinker with exactly what you are  appending, I am using the syntax you had) when you do your `executemany`.

Comment: I am trying to use method 1. I did as you told me.Then I inserted count = cursor.execute (sqlite_insert_query, Test1_text) "between" Test1_text = Test1.text and print. Is that the place you were referring to? I did well? I did the same thing with test 2. I get an error though, maybe it's about Vaules that I left it the same.In practice,there are 6 tests in my script,but as an example I have only included 2 in the question.So I get this error:sqlite3.ProgrammingError:Incorrect number of bindings supplied.The current statement uses 1, and there are 6 supplied.How to solve?Thank you

Comment: This looks like my bad on trying to pass a plain string. Give me a moment, and I will update.

Comment: I updated to add parentheses around the text to be added so it knows it's just one parameter. I also tried to clarify where the statement goes (basically where you had it). Please try and report back.

Comment: Everything is OK.Thanks. You are great.Scraping was working fine again and everything is saved in the database correctly.One question:there are 99 data being saved,that is 99 words in one vertical column.The final result of print,however,is 1. It prints:Record inserted successfully 1. I wrote print ("Record inserted successfully", cursor.rowcount)and then records_added_Results=records_added_Results +1.Shouldn't the result be 99?How can I get the result 99 and not 1?P.S:What difference is there if I enter "commit" only once at final close,or if I use it after each entry?Thank you

Comment: using way 1 you would need to records_added_Results=records_added_Results +1 each time you insert (and set to 0 before any of the tests) and use that variable, not cursor.rowcount, to print. Cursor.rowcount holds the rowcount from the last operation, which inserted just one row the way method 1 is working. I think one commit means if some error happens along the way things are not saved from memory to the database (so it's all or nothing). Multiple commits means it writes out each one right away. I think performance will be better with a single commit.

Comment: Maybe I didn't understand what you wrote (due to my translation problems). If I wanted to print, just once in the final, Record inserted successfully: 99, that is, that counts all the inserted records altogether, how should I write? Thank you

Comment: print ("Records inserted successfully: ", records_added_Risultati), just make sure you add one to records_added_Risultati each time you make an insert command.

Comment: I tried. It does not work. I can't get the final total number of records entered.

Comment: I must have been unclear somewhere. That should work. I edited the answer to include a new records_added variable and be clearer where it gets set to 0, where we add 1 to it, and where we print it.

Comment: Ah ok, thank you. Now it's all clear. Thank you. I put the green tick on the question as "resolved", but being new to SO, I can't rate your kind answer because I still have a few points. Excuse me. He will vote for it as soon as I can, in a few days. Don't worry, I won't forget. Thanks again. I am sending you to help me with this question as well please: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68596663/problem-database-with-foreign-key-for-a-combobox