# Problem database with foreign key for a combobox

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, python-2.7, sqlite

In a relationship database (SQLite) with foreign key, I have a table `Nations` containing nations inserted in random order like France, Italy, England, Japan.

Then I have another table `Cities` containing randomly placed cities like Tokyo, Paris, London, Rome, Bordeaux, Kyoto, Liverpool, Milan, etc.

I used a foreign key to relate cities to nations. I think I have done it well, the problem is that I can't enter every city in every related country.

For example I cannot do that: England = London, Liverpool; Japan = Tokyo, Kyoto.

To view this relationship between country and city I use two comboboxes: I would like to select a country in the first combobox and then in the second combobox I would like to display the relative cities of the selected country. What am I doing wrong? Why doesn't the relationship between cities and countries work?

Can you answer me show me the code please? Thank you

This is the `Nations` table:

```
CREATE TABLE "Nations_Table" 
(
    "ID_Nations"    INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    "Nations"   TEXT
);
```

This is the `Cities` table:

```
CREATE TABLE "Cities_Table" 
(
    "ID_Cities" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    "Cities"    TEXT,
    "ID_Nations"    INTEGER,
    FOREIGN KEY("ID_Nations") REFERENCES "Nation"("ID_Nations") 
         ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
);
```

This is the Python code I use, but it doesn't work correctly of course:

```
### COMBOBOX NATIONS ###
def combo_nations():
    cursor.execute('SELECT DISTINCT Nations_Table FROM Nation_Table')
    result=[row[0] for row in cursor]
    return result

 ### COMBOBOX CITIES ###
 def combo_cities(event=None):
     val = nations.get()
     cursor.execute('SELECT Cities_Table FROM xxxx WHERE xxxx = ?', (val,))
     result = [row[0] for row in cursor]
     citiesss['value'] = result
     citiesss.current(0)


nations=ttk.Combobox(window, width = 25)
nations['value'] = combo_nations()
nations.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', combo_cities)
nations.place(x=13, y=80)
nations.set("Choose Nations")

combo_cities=ttk.Combobox(window, width = 25)
combo_cities.place(x=13, y=120)
combo_cities.set("Choose Cities")
```

Comment: Your first SQL should be `SELECT Nations FROM Nations_Table`.  Your second should be `SELECT c.Cities FROM Cities_Table c, Nations_Table n WHERE c.ID_Nations=n.ID_Nations AND n.Nations = ?`.  Right?

Comment: @Tim Roberts What does "c" and "n" mean in what you wrote to me ? What are they for?But is the rest of the python code okay? Thank you

Comment: `c` is an alias for `Cities_Table` and `n` is an alias for `Nations_Table`, to reduce the amount of typing.  The code is approximately correct, although I haven't tried it yet.

Comment: So should I write like this? SELECT Cities_Table.Cities FROM Cities_Table Cities_Table, Nations_Table n WHERE Cities_Table.ID_Nations=Nations_Table.ID_Nations AND Nations_Table.Nations = ? 
Are you sure? Thank you :)

Comment: No, you write it just like I wrote it.  When you write `FROM Cities_Table c`, that tells SQL that `c` is a shortcut.  You can use `c` anywhere you would have used `Cities_Table`.

Comment: @Tim Roberts Ah okok. I'll try tomorrow night because it's late now. So is that all there is to it? If so, it's very simple. I thought there were also errors in the Python code related to the two comboboxes. Thank you. You are very kind

Comment: @Tim Roberts Sorry if I answer now: I don't connect much. I wrote the example code with Nations and Cities. In my case, the code is different, i.e. the names for the database are different. Can I use any other letter instead of "c" and "n"? Or are there any rules for aliasing these letters? (I don't know, for example that the letter of the alias must be the same as the first letter of the name?). Thank you

Comment: You need to read up on SQL.  This is very basic SQL syntax.

Comment: @Tim Roberts I know the SQL basics, but I haven't used typing aliases, so I was wondering. In the case of my question starts, if instead of "c" and "n" I used (for example) xxx and yyy, would that be fine too? Thank you

Comment: An alias can be anything that would be valid for a table name.  I usually use something related to the real table name, just so it isn't confusing.  So `c` or `ct` for `Cities_Table`, but that's just a convention.

Comment: @TimRoberts Perfect. Sorry if I answer now. I haven't logged in for a long time due to problems. If you answer me with an answer, I vote for you the answer. Thanks